# Dropbox API list_folder functions

Tags: dropbox-api

The Dropbox API provides two functions to list the contents of a folder

- [list_folders](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_folders) and
- [list_folders_continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_folders)

with both returning a `has_more:true` when the listing has not yet been completed.  I created 1000 dummy files in my Dropbox apps folder and tested them out.  Even with that many files the full listing was returned by the `list_folders` function.  That is not a problem.  However, I would like to know **when**, i.e at what sort of file count, `has_more:true` will occur.  I hope that someone here will have the answer

---

With 5010 files I had `have_more` set two times.  The file counts were 2000, 2000 and 1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of factors control when you'll get a partial result with `has_more:true`. If you just want to trigger it for testing purposes, just try more files. (I'd guess that by, say, 5000 you'll trigger it.)

In your production app, you should just be ready to handle it at any time, since there are no guarantees about when it will happen.

Comment: "You should just be ready to handle it at any time, since there are no guarantees about when it will happen" - this makes it unnecessarily difficult to test though. Going by what @DroidOS had to go through, where not only a lot of work has to be done to create this many items, it is also a guessing game as to when it will happen. Please consider adding a limit parameter to this call - search already supports it. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483875/dropbox-api-v2-confusion-with-cursor-and-paging-for-list-folders