# Dropbox Api v2 - confusion with cursor and paging for list_folders

Tags: dropbox-api

The files/list _folders method in api docs has the following for the description of the cursor parameter:

**cursor** - Pass the cursor into list_folder/continue to see what's changed in the folder since your previous query.

**has_more** - If true, then there are more entries available. Pass the cursor to list_folder/continue to retrieve the rest.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder

Which is it then? If I make another request to list_folders_continue passing in the token, am I requesting another page of results or changes to the folder? If I am requesting another page of results, what is the limit that was applied? And can I control that?

The docs also have the list_folder method under **sharing**, which appears to have more precise definition of the cursor and the support for the limit parameter
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_folders

Will the method under **files** have that too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which is it then? If I make another request to list_folders_continue passing in the token, am I requesting another page of results or changes to the folder?

It's both. The /files/list_folder/continue endpoint is used both for returning additional pages of items, as well as getting further updates in the future.

Each page returned by /files/list_folder[/continue] is limited in size, but there is no guaranteed limit, nor can you control that limit. Your app should just always check `has_more` and call back to /files/list_folder/continue if it is `true`.

Also, the endpoints [/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder) and [/sharing/list_folders](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_folders) are different endpoints with different functionality.

The /files/list_folder endpoint is documented as:

> Returns the contents of a folder.

The /sharing/list_folders endpoint is documented as:

> Return the list of all shared folders the current user has access to.

The two endpoints use different cursors, for use with [/files/list_folder/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue) and [/sharing/list_folders/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_folders-continue), respectively.

Comment: Do you know what the limit is? Not sure how we can test the pagination without knowing it. How many files, folders do I need to create in order to get the response with a cursor for another page? Adding the ability to specify the limit would be even better, especially when other parts of the api already support it - search, sharing/list_folders. Seems like in a short term it would be good to publish what the limit/max_results is, in the long run, to add the limit/max_results parameter for /files/list_folder.

Comment: The limit can vary, but generally it's 1-2k items. We'll consider this a request for being able to control it.

Comment: That would be good @Greg. Also noticed this related question - looks like in that case 5k items was a suggested number of items. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237283/dropbox-api-list-folder-functions

Comment: I"m still confused about how the cursor is "both" for continuation or for monitoring changes.  Do you mean "either"?  As in, if there is "has_more", then the subsequent call to list_folder/continue with that cursor returns the "more", and if not, it returns changes?  I mean, there has to be a clear semantic for whether you're getting additional items or changes, and I can't tell from the docs what it is.

Comment: It is for both. Initially, you call through all of the pages until `has_more=false`. Then after some time passes, you can call again and you'll get any new entries/changes. The "entries" can represent both items that you didn't yet know about, or changes to existing ones that you did know about. The [/files/list_folder documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder) describes the process for handling them in either case.

Comment: OK, maybe this is semantic.  The "cursor" in a general sense serves both purposes (monitoring for changes or getting subsequent pages), but a given instances of a cursor seems to be either one or the other (based on fairly extensive testing).  I've added a new answer that clarifies that, and the logic needed to get all pages or contents and to monitor for changes.  I read the docs many times before diving in and testing myself, and I found the docs to be very ambiguous/unclear.

Comment: The uncontrollable limit thing is ridiculous. I need to test if /continue works well in the app I was asked to make. In testing what the limit is (**2k**, apparently), I ran into many timeouts and eventually rate limiting. Not to mention the memory to store the gson of a 1MB response...

Comment: You can now set an approximate limit on the [list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder) page size using the `limit` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

> Which is it then? If I make another request to list_folders_continue
>   passing in the token, am I requesting another page of results or
>   changes to the folder? If I am requesting another page of results,
>   what is the limit that was applied? And can I control that?

My own trial and error experimentation has determined that the "It's both" answer posted by Greg is not correct.  Specifically, the correct answer is "it's either".  See below for more details.

When you call `files/list_folder` and it returns the entire list of contents (with a `has_more` value of `false`), then the cursor returned is suitable for monitoring subsequent changes to the path specified by passing that cursor to `files/list_folder/continue`.

If `files/list_folder` returns the first of multiple pages of contents (with a `has_more` value of `true`), then the cursor returned is suitable for getting the next page of contents by passing it to `files/list_folder/continue`.  This cursor is not suitable for monitoring for changes (try it yourself, you can call continue as many times as you want with that cursor and you will always get the second page of contents).

It's not entirely clear from the docs, but when getting pages of contents from `files/list_folder/continue`, each call will return a new cursor, and that new cursor must be passed to a subsequent call to `files/list_folder/continue` in order to get the next page.  You must chain the cursors together in this way until you get the last page (where `has_more` is `false`).

The cursor returned in that last call to `files/list_folder/continue` can then be used in subsequent calls to `files/list_folder/continue` to monitor for changes to the original path specified in the very first call to `files/list_folder`.

So the cursor is either suitable for monitoring for changes (when it is returned with a `has_more` value of `false`) OR it is suitable for getting a subsequent page of contents (when it is returned with a `has_more` value of `true`), regardless of whether the call that produced the cursor was `files/list_folder` or `files/list_folder/continue`, but it is never both.

Comment: Another clue here is that the results come back sorted by `server_modified` time, with the oldest entries first.  So the cursor is really just pointing to a point in that time-sorted list (which explains why the cursor returned at the end of a complete listing allows you to monitor for changes).